# Why updateMany didnt mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cannot solve this problem. Other words updateMany and updateOne cannot work :

```
router.post('/deleteChat', async (req, res) => {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) return res.status(400).json({message: "User cant loginned"});
    
    const {currentConversation} = req.body;

    try {
        await Messages.updateMany({ $and: [ {about: currentConversation._id}, {who_delete: { $nin: [req.user._id] } } ] }, {$push: {who_delete: req.user._id} } )
        await Conversation.updateOne( {$and: [ {_id: currentConversation._id}, {status: {$nin: [req.user._id] } } ] }, {$push: {status: req.user._id }} )
        return res.json()
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: "Something wrong went!"})
    }
    
});
```

I want to say if user cannot inside array then add insert array. But I cannot do this? What I need use `$ne` or `$nin`?

Comment: when it failed to mongoose, did it return an error message?

Comment: use $nin as $ne is for checking equality